# SVG2PDF compilation problems

Tags: windows, pdf, svg

I'm trying to compile this and having no success (Win32) using CYGWIN... make gives me a load of unreferenced functions which appear to be part of the Cairo dependency (I have the source for this and still the errors persist)

Is there a binary available that I can download?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually built Cairo, or just downloaded the source?  You'll need to build it first.  If you have, you're probably missing a -I or -L flag, which are used to tell GCC where to look for header files and libraries.  Also, could be a missing -l which specifies a library to include in the link process.

Could you copy & paste some error messages?

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for responding.  I've not built Cairo, just downloaded the source as Svg2Pdf.c has references to `cairo-pdf.h` only.  I'm a complete novice with CYGWIN - it seems like the dependency tree for this simple application could be absolutely enormous? I can't give you errors just now as it's on a colleagues machine and he has gone home... but I expect they are related.

Comment: You are missing cairo-pdf.  Try installing the cygwin package "libcairo-devel" and see if that gets you any further along.